# Order of results from python's dir() function

Tags: python

The `dir()`of a class can be customized by creating a special function which returns a user-defined list, so why does it not maintain the order I specified?  Here's an example:

```
>>> class C(object):
...   def __dir__(self):
...     return ['a', 'c', 'b']
...
>>> c = C()
>>> dir(c)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Why is `dir()` seemingly sorting my list and returning `['a', 'b', 'c']` rather than `['a', 'c', 'b']`?

Oddly (to me), calling the member function directly yields the expected results:

```
>>> c.__dir__()
['a', 'c', 'b']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by definition of the `dir()` built-in. It explicitly alphabetizes the list of names:

```
Help on built-in function dir in module __builtin__:

dir(...)
   dir([object]) -> list of strings

   If called without an argument, return the names in the current scope.
   Else, return an alphabetized list of names comprising (some of) the attributes
   of the given object, and of attributes reachable from it.
   If the object supplies a method named __dir__, it will be used; otherwise
   the default dir() logic is used and returns:
     for a module object: the module's attributes.
     for a class object:  its attributes, and recursively the attributes
       of its bases.
     for any other object: its attributes, its class's attributes, and
       recursively the attributes of its class's base classes.
```

Comment: And they say there are no silly questions...  At any rate, thanks for at least verifying that I wasn't imagining things.  Guess next time I should rtm.  Thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of the dir function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) says:

> The resulting list is sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

since in modern python versions dicts are ordered,
You can get the fields of a class in the order they were created.
the following function delivers back the non-private attributes of a class.
if the object does not provide `__dict__`  or `__slots__`, it falls back and delivers the sorted list of attributes.

There can be edge cases were `__dict__` or `__slots__` does not contain all attributes (Metaclasses? Subclassing? - You need to check, the full functionality of `dir(object)` is complex).

if You pass a **Class** to the function:

- "normal" Classes have `__dict__`, therefore it **IS** possible to get the unsorted list.
- slotted Classes have `__slots__`, therefore it **IS** possible to get the unsorted list

if You pass an **instance of a Class** to the function:

- Instances of "normal" Classes dont have `__dict__`, therefore it is not possible to get the unsorted list.
- Instances of slotted Classes have `__slots__`, therefore it **IS** possible to get the unsorted list

```
from typing import Any, List

def get_public_fields_of_an_object(the_object: Any) -> List[str]:
    """
    gets the public attributes of an object, if possible 
    the creation order is preserved
    """
    if hasattr(the_object, '__dict__'):
        fields = the_object.__dict__.keys()
    elif hasattr(the_object, '__slots__'):
        fields = the_object.__slots__
    else:
        fields = dir(the_object)
    fields = [field for field in fields if not field.startswith('_')]
    return fields
```

Comment: Please note that for a class with a parent, `cls.__dict__` does not include attributes of parent class. So you have to use both  `cls.__dict__`  and `dir(cls)`.

Comment: Actually we should loop over `cls.__bases__ + (cls,)`

Comment: @saeedgnu, good point. people need to take care about that.